# if/elif question, it works, but the answer is wrong

Tags: python-3.x

```
age = 20

if age < 2:
    
    print('the person is a baby')

elif age >= 2:
    
    print('toddler')

elif age >= 4:
    
    print('kid')

elif age >= 13:

    print('teenager')

elif age >= 20:
    
    print('adult')

elif age >= 65:
    
    print('elder')
```

it works, but when age is more and 2, the answer is always toddler. I do not know what happened.

Comment: Anything greater than 4 or 13 or 20 is also greater than 2, so all of these go into the first `elif`. You need to check for ranges instead, e.g. age >=2 and age < 4 is Toddler, age >= 4 and age < 13 is Kid, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya that's obvious

If one of your `elif` statement got executed then rest of all `elif` or `else` will be ignored

You can specify conserver condition with the `elif` condition

example::

```
if age < 2:
   print('the person is a baby')

elif age >= 2 and age < 4:
   print('toddler')

elif age >= 4 and age < 13:
   print('kid')

else:
   print('Out')
```

Likewise you can limit the conditions.

Comment: It's fine to say:  elif 2 <= age < 4: